# Jest or Mocha with Vue: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

Edit: This post got out of hand with edits, please follow this link to a new Stackoverflow post which is clearer:
[SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when following vue-test-utils official tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636339/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-following-vue-tes)

There are thousands of posts and threads about this issue and I still can't fix my problem.
I followed the "Getting started" portions of Jest AND Mocha and get the same error both times:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` but their provided [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) doesn't help at all.

Theres a new edit at the bottom with steps for a clean new project with jest for you to follow along which results in an error.

`"vue-jest": "^3.0.7"`,
`"vue": "^2.6.12"`,
`"@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2"`

**package.json**

```json
"mocha": "mocha 'tests/Frontend/**/*.test.js'"
```

**example.test.js:**

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Dashboard from "../../resources/js/views/Dashboard";
import * as assert from "assert";

describe('test example', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1); // doesn't matter what I do here
    })
})
```

**What I've tried:**

- Using the `--require @babel/register` flag with mocha
- Setting `"transformIgnorePatterns": []` and thus allowing all node_modules to be considered
- Adding a `.babelrc` file with the following content: 
   This resulted in following error on building the app though:

```
Error: Multiple configuration files found. Please remove one:
 - package.json
 - C:\Users\f.marchi\workspace\projects\sanctum-test\.babelrc
```

```json
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone confirm, that those docs are missing some very important steps? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm just following the tutorials.

Edit: **jest.config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,

    collectCoverage: true,

    coverageDirectory: "coverage",

    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "json",
        "vue"
    ],
    transform: {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: []
};
```

Edit:
I just tried again, you can follow along if you want:

1. vue create jest-test
2. npm install --save-dev jest @vue/test-utils vue-jest
3. Added jest config to package.json:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

4. npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0
5. Adjusted jest config to:

```js
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      // process `*.js` files with `babel-jest`
      ".*\\.(js)$": "babel-jest" //<-- changed this
    }
  }
}
```

6. Adjusted babel config to:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
        '@babel/preset-env' //<-- added this
    ]
};
```

Comment: Could you share jest.config.js?

Comment: I added it as an edit.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg I made a new post because this one got out of hand with edits. Please follow this link to the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636339/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-following-vue-tes

Comment: See my answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641269/1181067).

Answer (score -1):

You should use [vue-cli API](https://cli.vuejs.org/dev-guide/ui-api.html).

In your package.json add to scripts this:

```
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
```

You have vue-cli and test-utils installed so it should now work.