# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when following vue-test-utils official tutorial

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

I can't get vue testing to work with vue-test-utils and jest. I created a clean new project with vue cli and added jest as follows, maybe someone can follow along and tell me what I'm doing wrong. (I'm following this installation guide: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#semantic-versioning)

1. `vue create jest-test`

   1.1. `npm install`
2. `npm install --save-dev jest @vue/test-utils vue-jest`
3. Added jest config to package.json:

   ```json
   {
     "jest": {
       "moduleFileExtensions": [
         "js",
         "json",
         "vue"
       ],
       "transform": {
         ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. `npm install --save-dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0`
5. Adjusted jest config to:

   ```js
   {
     "jest": {
       "transform": {
         // process `*.js` files with `babel-jest`
         ".*\\.(js)$": "babel-jest" //<-- changed this
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   6. Adjusted babel config to:

   ```js
   module.exports = {
       presets: [
           '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
           '@babel/preset-env' //<-- added this
       ]
   };
   ```
6. Created example.test.js in a tests directory under the project root (jest-test/tests)
7. Added the following to this file:

   ```js
   import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
   import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld";


   test('displays message', () => {
       const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld)

       expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Welcome to Your Vue.js App')
   })
   ```
8. Added the following to the package.json scripts:
   `"jest": "jest"`
9. `npm run jest`
10. Get the following error:

    ```
    C:\Users\xxx\jest-test\tests\example.test.js:1
        import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
        ^^^^^^

        SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    ```

Same happens with Mocha or if I try it in an existing project. Is this a bug? I can't get it working, no matter what I do.

Edit: If I do it with Vue CLI, it works
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#installation-with-vue-cli-recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform both `*.vue` files and `*.js` files.
I tried your setup and could reproduce the issue. But after altering `jest.config.js` to the following, the tests will run fine:

```
module.exports = {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  transform: {
    '.*\\.js$':'babel-jest',
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
}
```

Comment: This solved it! Thank you!

So can you agree with me that the official documentation doesn't work when you follow the steps 1to1? 
Because this part: `".*\\.js$":"babel-jest"` is not in the docs and even if this is not Vue.js specific, their tutorial doesn't work without it.

Comment: My test project was fixed with this. In my "real" project  I get the following error:  `ReferenceError: axios is not defined`. I thought this was fixable by adding `"axios"` to the `transformIgnorePatterns` array. That did work but resulted in anohter error: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. This one doesn't get solved if I add it to the array. Even if I set the array to empty: `transformIgnorePatterns: [],` (so all packages are considered) the error remains.
Can you help me with this as well?

Comment: I'm not sure about the official documentation. I think this works because I use 'jsdom' as the testEnvironment. For axios I always mock requests. You could use a solution like https://github.com/knee-cola/jest-mock-axios.